# Problem defining associations in sequelize, I get 'Unknown Column' for the foreignKey used in the association

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to use sequelize to interface with my MySQL db. The Database connection is setup fine, I can add, get, update entries. The main problem is when I define associations.

I want to define an 'Owner' association between my 'Chain' and 'User' models, where a 'Chain' can have one Owner User, but a 'User' can own many 'Chains'.

```
function initModels(sequelize) {
  var chains = _chains(sequelize, DataTypes);
  var users = _users(sequelize, DataTypes);
  chains.belongsTo(users, {foreignKey: "OwnerID", as : 'owner'});
}
```

Here is where I create the sequelize instance, and I wonder if I need to Sequelize.sync() here at some point?

```
var initModels = require("../models/init-models");


const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const process = require('process');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

var models = initModels(sequelize);
```

And here is the post request.

```
router.post("/addOwner" , async (req, res) => {

    const { ChainID, UserID } = req.body;

  try {
    // Find the chain by ID
    const chain = await models.chains.findByPk(ChainID);
    if (!chain) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Chain not found' });
    }

    // Find the user by ID
    const user = await models.users.findByPk(UserID);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }

    // Set the owner of the chain
    await chain.setOwner(user);

    return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Owner added successfully' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error); //error caught here
    return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }


})
```

I get the error

```
{
    code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'OwnerID' in 'field list'",
    sql: 'SELECT `ChainID`, `Title`, `Bio`, `DateCreated`, `ImagesCount`, `ChainType`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt`, `OwnerID` FROM `chains` AS `chains` WHERE `chains`.`ChainID` = 1;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
```

For some reason sequelize isn't creating the necessary columns for the defined association?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You didn't mention how you created tables in the DB in the first place. Please enlighten me about that (maybe the best way would be to update the post itself rather than commenting here)